# Continuous flow calorimeter specific heat capacity of water heat loss problem

Tags: thermodynamics

In this experiment [continuous flow calorimeter](https://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Thermal%20physics/Heat%20energy/text/Specific_heat_capacity_measurement/index.html)
I'm struggling to understand why the heat loss from the water is the same in both cases.
If the flow rate is different, there is a different mass of water passing through in the same period of time. If the temperature difference is the same in both cases, how can the energy loss be the same if the mass is different?
I'm probably just being an idiot but I've not found anything that explains this.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: They are assuming that the heat transfer coefficient between the flowing liquid and the surroundings is the same in both cases.  Heat loss H is assumed to be equal to the heat transfer area times the heat transfer coefficient times the log-mean temperature difference with the surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

The heat loss they refer to in the experiment is the heat lost in the apparatus. Not the energy "lost" to the fluid.

If the temperature conditions are approximately the same in everywhere the apparatus in the 2 experiments, then heat loss to the surroundings will be approximately the same.

This is not saying that the same amount of energy is transferred to the liquid (this is not the heat loss).

In the 2 experiments different amounts of energy is transferred to the liquid, at different flow rates. But the apparatus as an object has the same temperature and therefore looses the same amount of energy = heat loss.

The identical heat loss creates the clever correspondence in the 2 experiments.